# How do I assert for a link's href AND link text in a functional test?

Tags: 8, testing

In a functional test, I can use `WebAssert::linkByHrefExists()` to check that a link with a specific href exists on the page. And I can use `WebAssert::linkExists()` to check that a link with a specific link text exists on the page.

But there's no guarantee that these two will find the same link! How do I check that a link on the page has the expected href AND text?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a better approach will be assert by XPath selector `\Drupal\Tests\BrowserTestBase::xpath` something like `'//a[@href="' . $url .'"][contains(text()=\'Some text\')]'` as XPath. Check this post about [matching text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078308/selenium-and-xpath-locating-a-link-by-containing-text) and this about [matching url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155454/how-to-find-an-element-by-href-value-using-selenium-python/33155512).

Comment: I'd rather avoid xpath, as I find it really hard to write and read. See my answer for something I've come up with using Mink traversal.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some poking around with Mink's selectors and the methods available on its element objects, and I can manage this:

```
$this->assertEquals('/expected/link/path', $page->findLink("Expected Link Text")->getAttribute('href'));
```

It's not quite as readable as the WebAssert methods though.

Comment: But since you get the link first by text, what happens if you have two links with same text on the page? But I think is a subject for another use case